# Unable to open file 'VCLE40.LIB' (C++ Builder)

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, c++builder, legacy, lib

I've recently been tasked to develop on an old project, however upon an attempt to compile I'm receiving a fatal linker error:

```
[Linker Fatal Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'VCLE40.LIB'
```

From some research, I understand the file was used in C++Builder 4 - however, I am using C++ Builder 6 (as that is what was on the machine that the old developer used, and given to me for work) and VCLE40.lib is not supported anymore.

I have tried to find any links to the library in the .BPK file and throughout the project to no avail.

Any suggestions?

Comment: VCLE40.LIB only exists in C++Builder 4.  The corresponding filename  in C++Builder 6 is VCLE.LIB instead (version numbers were dropped from BPI/LIB files of BPLs in BCB6).  You need to edit the project to update any VCLE references accordingly. A better option is to not migrate an old project file to a newer IDE to begin with. Create a new project fresh in the new IDE and then migrate existing source files to it as needed

Comment: I have just attempted this, however upon compilation it still brings up the same error unfortunately. I created a new project and the only files which I migrated were .cpp, .h and report layout files (.rdf, .rpt, .inv) which do not include any reference to VCLE40. Would the old lib/include files cause issues (.lib, .obj and .bpi files)? I think I would have issues replacing some of those.

Comment: I have found an offending object using tdump grep that uses 'vcle40.lib' - I am going to see what I can do to make a new object file that doesn't but I am not entirely sure how to go about doing so; I will try however.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: old object files included were built using old version of C++ Builder: rebuilding the offending files solved the issue and removed the dependency.